# Hypothesis on Finding Remainders

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, integers

I'm currently new to math.stackexchange, i figured i'd come here after finding a statement on remainders which i'm currently unable to prove :

> Let ***P,Q***  be positive integers with ***P*** greater than ***Q***, and ***M*** = ***P*** $mod$  ***Q***. Then for every possible combination of values of ***P*** and ***Q***, the maximum value of ***M*** attainable : $$ M_{max} = ({{10^d}} - 1) $$ where $d$ denotes the number of digits of ***Q***.

As for today, i haven't found a proof for this statement (nor it's truth value) in math.stackexchange archives. I'd value help and constructive criticisms very much. Thank you.

Comment: How about something like $6 = 13 \mod 7$? The number of digits of $7$ is $1$, so $M_{max}$ should be $4$, but here it is $6$. For a more drastic example, $8 = 17 \mod 9$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг wow you're right! i think i misunderstood the original idea. How about Mmax = (10^d - 1), without the division by two?

Comment: This is correct! The reason is very simple: if $Q$ has $d$ digits, then $Q$ is less than or equal to $99..99$ , where the $9$ repeats $d$ times. (For example, if $Q$ has three digits, then $Q \leq 999$). Now, you can check that $10^d - 1 = 999...999$ (repeated $d$ times). So the proof follows since $M \leq Q \leq 10^d - 1$. A slightly harder question: Why is it true that $M \leq 10^d - 2$?! (and you can't go further than this!)